# Handle 404 errors in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, http-status-code-404

Here is the code I have for redirecting unmapped requests to 404 page

```
@RequestMapping("/**")
    public ModelAndView redirect() {

    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
    mv.setViewName("errorPage");        
        return mv;
    }
```

The above code works fine but the problem is with the web resources like css and js files 
also go inside this redirect method and it is not loading any of the files. But i already have this code in my dispatcher servlet,but spring controller is not recognizing this resources mapping.

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/WEB-INF/web-resources/" />
```

so i tried some **regex expression** in the request mapping to negate the resources url something like this

```
@RequestMapping("/{^(?!.*resources/**)}**")
    public ModelAndView redirect() {

    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
    mv.setViewName("errorPage");        
        return mv;
    }
```

But this is not working as expected ..So if anyone could help it would be great :)

Comment: You are making things to complex, simply change the order in which URLs are processed, the /** has always to be last. Can you add your configuration?

Comment: yes i tried to make /** as last even though /resources/** go to the redirect method

Comment: As stated please add yuor config to the question.

Comment: you mean the dipatcher servlet.xml ?

Comment: web.xml and indeed your servlet.xml...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to handle 404 (Unmapped links), I used a SimpleUrlHandlerMapping to do this.

I added the below code to my **dispatcher servlet .xml**

```
<!-- Here all your resources like css,js will be mapped first -->
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/WEB-INF/web-resources/" /> 
    <context:annotation-config />

<!-- Next is your request mappings from controllers -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.xyz" /> 
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

<!-- Atlast your error mapping -->
    <bean id="errorUrlBean" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
       <property name="mappings">
        <props>
           <prop key="/**">errorController</prop>
         </props>
       </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="errorController" class="com.xyz.controller.ErrorController">

    </bean>
```

**com.xyz.controller.ErrorController class**

```
public class ErrorController extends AbstractController  {


    @Override
    protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest arg0,
            HttpServletResponse arg1) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        mv.setViewName("errorPage");        
        return mv;
    }

}
```

I found the below reasons

`@RequestMapping("/**")`  uses **RequestHandlerMapping** and

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/WEB-INF/web-resources/" />
```

uses **SimpleUrlHandlerMapping**

RequestHandlerMapping takes presedence over SimpleUrlHandlerMapping, so that was the reason all resources request went inside the redirect method in my case.

So i just changed the `@RequestMapping("/**")` request to SimpleUrlHandlerMapping by configuring that as a bean as given above in my dipatcher servlet and mapped it at the last and it solved the problem.

Also add the below code to your **web.xml**

```
  <error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/error.jsp</location>
  </error-page>
```

Now this simple solution can be used to redirect all unmapped requests i.e) 404 errors to an error page :)