# Can not handle unmapped urls/404 errors in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I want to handle unmapped urls/404 errors in Spring MVC App I have found an example [Here SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23008900/handle-404-errors-in-spring/23054815#23054815), I Java Based Configuration and tried in this way

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.app.controller" })
public class ServletConfigurer extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    private Properties errorResolverProperties;
    private Properties errorProperties;     
    /// Here I'm configuring <beans as mentioned in SO Answer
    @Bean
    public SimpleUrlHandlerMapping simpleUrlHandlerMapping() {
        SimpleUrlHandlerMapping simpleUrlHandlerMapping = new SimpleUrlHandlerMapping();
        errorResolverProperties = new Properties();
        errorProperties = new Properties();
        errorProperties.put("/**", pageNotFoundController());
        errorResolverProperties.put("mappings", errorProperties);       
        return simpleUrlHandlerMapping;
    }
    // this is my Controller
    @Bean
    public PageNotFoundController pageNotFoundController(){
        return new PageNotFoundController();
    }

    @Bean
    public TilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer() {
        TilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer = new TilesConfigurer();
        tilesConfigurer.setDefinitions("/WEB-INF/tiles_xml/tiles.xml");
        return tilesConfigurer;     
    }       
}
```

My controller is

```
@Controller
public class PageNotFoundController {
    @ExceptionHandler
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    public String handleINFException(PageNotFoundException ex) {
        return "error";
    }
}
```

and finally the

```
public class PageNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {    

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public PageNotFoundException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

but it always shows the same error page of Apache not the custom/my error page.

## UPDATE

```
public class AppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {  

        WebApplicationContext rootContext = getWebApplicationContext();
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext)); 
        servletContext.setInitParameter("defaultHtmlEscape", "true");
        // add the dispatcher servlet and map it to /
        DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = new DispatcherServlet(rootContext);
        dispatcherServlet.setThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound(true);
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet(
                "springDispatcher", dispatcherServlet);
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");
    }

    private AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext getWebApplicationContext() {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        context.setConfigLocation("com.app.config");
        return context;
    }

}
```

that is it..

Comment: Please add your web.xml file, did you define error-page at web.xml file?

Comment: Sorry but I have Java Based Config _no web.xml_.

Comment: Sorry i realize now maybe this url may help http://stackoverflow.com/a/30785549/1577363

Answer (score 2):

If you want to catch it globally, you need a ControllerAdvice:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandlerController {
    public static final String DEFAULT_ERROR_VIEW = "error";
    public static final String STATUS_CODE = "404";
    public static final String TYPE = "Custom Type";

    @ExceptionHandler(value = {NoHandlerFoundException.class})
    public ModelAndView defaultErrorHandler(HttpServletRequest request, Exception e) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView(DEFAULT_ERROR_VIEW);
        mav.addObject("timestamp", new Date());
        mav.addObject("status", STATUS_CODE);
        mav.addObject("type", TYPE);
        mav.addObject("message", String.format("The requested url is: %s", request.getRequestURL()));
        return mav;
    }
}
```

Now you need to activate, that an Exception is thrown in case of 404:

```
@Autowired
public void configureDispatcher(DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet){
    dispatcherServlet.setThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound(true);
}
```

Insert it in any @Configuration annotated class.

That's it!

**UPDATE**

Change your class to

```
@Configuration
public class AppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {   
        WebApplicationContext rootContext = getWebApplicationContext();
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext)); 
        servletContext.setInitParameter("defaultHtmlEscape", "true");
    }

    private AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext getWebApplicationContext() {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        context.setConfigLocation("com.app.config");
        return context;
    }

   @Autowired
   public void configureDispatcher(DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet){
       dispatcherServlet.setThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound(true);
   }

}
```

Comment: It gives exception __Could not autowire method: public void configureDispatcher(org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}__

Comment: Without any additional configuration it works with Spring Boot, how did you configure your project?

Comment: Is your ControllerAdvice within your component-scan package? Do you see a NoHandlerFoundException in the log? Can you set a breakpoint in the advice?

Comment: You have to use the configureDispatcher. I think the problem is, that you create a new DispatcherServlet manually in your onStartup.

Comment: See my update above. You need to add @Configuration to your AppInitializer class.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100580/discussion-between-dactabird-and-arshad-ali).